# View is not a constructor for Backbone under Typescript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

I am trying to create a Backbone.js view in Typescript. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ExampleView is not a constructor in http://localhost:57258/Tests/spec/ExampleViewTest.js (line 17)
```

My view is instantiated like this:

```
var view = new ExampleView();
```

The view is declared like this:

```
///<reference path="../Scripts/typings/backbone/backbone.d.ts"/>

class ExampleView extends Backbone.View {   
    constructor(options?: Backbone.ViewOptions) {
        super(options);
    }
};
```

**Update:** Looking through the "compiled javascript file", the error the Browser gives is on the second last line: Backbone is undefined. How would I import it?

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var ExampleView = (function (_super) {
    __extends(ExampleView, _super);
    function ExampleView() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return Av;
})(Backbone.Model);
//# sourceMappingURL=av.js.map
```

Comment: Usually Backbone views are created using `Backbone.View.extend(...)`, yet you appear to be using native JavaScript prototypal inheritance. This could be the issue. You might need to use `Backbone.View.extend(...)` instead.

Comment: The reason that I use the "extends" keyword is that it is recommended in the Typescript version of Backbone. They have actually blocked the use of `Backbone.View.extend(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Backbone is undefined. How would I import it?

Using a script tag. Or an external module loader like `requirejs` along with AMD modules (`--module amd`). More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1